# Constant crashing/freezing during installation of dual booting Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, crash, screen-corruption

I've been trying to dual boot my pc to have Ubuntu 18.04.2 alongside with Windows 10, but I'm having problems with this.

During the Ubuntu installation, there are alot of "crashing/freezing" that occurs. It happens randomly too, most of the time it happens as soon as the mouse appear on screen, but one time It leaved me alone long enough to let me install ubuntu, but after that It still keeps crashing.

I don't know what makes it do so and I don't know how to fix it. So I'm asking about this here now.

Some info I think may help:
-I'm using a 64bit hp pc with amd ryzen 5 1400 processor.
-When it crashes/freezes, the screen gets all corrupted and I can't do anything, making me need to force shutdown my pc.
-I disabled secure boot and fast boot in the bios, aswell as disabling fast startup while following a guide.
-The crashing doesn't happen when using recovery mode (edit: actually after using recovery mode long enough it froze, but didn't get the corrupted screen), nor does It happen in virtualbox. It doesn't crash in Windows 10 either, infact Windows 10 runs just like normally.
-I used a usb flash drive to install Ubuntu, redid It a couple of times but the problem is still there every time.
-It doesn't happen during grub menu, But It happens whether I'm booting up Ubuntu or choosing either of the options "try Ubuntu without installing", "install Ubuntu", "Check disc for defects" during installation. I've checked disc for defects and It says It's all good.
-I'm installing Ubuntu on a separate hard drive (1TB) from Windows 10. Something I've heard is recommended from some people, but I choose to have some storage partition in that secondary drive for Windows 10 since I'm kinda running low on space on my main ssd.

I'm just completely clueless and tired of this. I'm sorry, I'm quite new to Linux.

Comment: @user535733 Really? But the usb drive is brand new, bought it a few days ago.

Comment: Look up how to test your USB drive using Windows.

Comment: @user535733 Just tested with "RMPrepUSB" and "h2testw", both of them said It's all good.

Comment: Well, now you know for sure. Happy to withdraw my failed hypothesis.

Comment: Appreciate your attempt to help anyway.

Comment: What is your video card?

Comment: My graphics card is a Radeon(TM) RX 580.